# How to get a transaction records within a day

Tags: stellar-laboratory

How to get a transaction record within a day? I am new to Stellar so how do I do this in Java? Is there any way?

Comment: Are you asking how to get all transaction records for a specific day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This working, *untested* Java code will print all transaction hashes from the preceding 24 hours:

```
long ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24;

DateTimeFormatter dateParser = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
long now = ZonedDateTime.now().toEpochSecond();

Server server = new Server("https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org");
TransactionsRequestBuilder txnRequests = server.transactions().limit(200)
    .order(RequestBuilder.Order.DESC);

List<TransactionResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();
Page<TransactionResponse> page = txnRequests.execute();

boolean limitHit = false;
while (!limitHit) {
    page.getRecords().removeIf(txn -> {
        ZonedDateTime txnDateTime = 
            ZonedDateTime.parse(txn.getCreatedAt(), dateParser);
        return now - txnDateTime.toEpochSecond() > ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS;
    });

    if (page.getRecords().isEmpty()) {
        limitHit = true;
    } else {
        responses.addAll(page.getRecords());
        String pagingToken = responses.get(responses.size() - 1).getPagingToken();
        page = server.transactions().limit(200).order(RequestBuilder.Order.DESC)
            .cursor(pagingToken).execute();
    }
}

responses.forEach(txn -> {
    System.out.println("txn = " + txn.getHash());
});
```

Comment: is there a way to do this for specific account id

Comment: @srbyk1990 Yes there is. Just add `.forAccount(KeyPair)` onto the transaction lookup chain. e.g. `server.transactions().forAccount(myAccn).limit(200)...`

Answer (score 2):

If you want just today's tx, just curl the Horizon "transaction" endpoint is ok. Example with testnet:  https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions?order=desc

Crawl the "next" page recursively to check if there are still tx created today.

.

By default, only 10 tx are listed in every page. You may increase it, for example, to 150: https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions?limit=150&order=desc (Note: largest possible return limit is 200)

The "cursor" parameter can be helpful, but it is DB stuff and unlikely you will use it. If you wish to find **all tx of a certain day**, you need to build your own Horizon and query the DB yourself. There is a transaction_history table containing tx timestamps.

Note: Timestamps are of UTC.

---

Better have quick check at Laboratory to see if this suits what you want..

[image]